# Initial weights Feed Forward NN

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, gradient-descent

I am trying to understand the purpose of Xavier's initialization of the weights in an ANN. I get that the main reason is that we don't like our linear combinations in the units to be very large as the class sigmoid functions has then a zero derivative and therefore we are suffering a vanishing gradient. From my understanding, the variance of the linear combinations in our units of a layer increases a lot if the previous layer has many units because the linear combination has a lot of elements. The resulting variance will then sum up the variances of each (previous layer) units result (assuming they are uncorrelated). In order to ensure that the variance remains at 1, one considers the number of units in the previous layer and addapt the distribution from which the random weights are drawn respectively. I hope this is correct until now.

First, is it correct to say: "A high variance of the linear combination makes it more probable to have a vanishing gradient."?

Second, in an article I have read "...these problems are more pronounced when dealing with deep ANNs...". Why is the depth, so the number of layers, a problem? I would say that the number of units in the layers is rather the source of the problem. If I think about an ANN with 50 layers but each layer has only few units I don't see where the problem of initializing weights random instead of using Xaviers approach come from.